# How to specify exact number of columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text files to read that have no headers.
I specified the parameter

```
  header=None
```

This is fine.

I am using the following statement to read the files

```
  pd.read_csv(fname, '\t', header=None, quotechar=None, quoting=3)
```

So, I am using the tab separator.

Following is the sample file

```
   a    b   c
   a    b   c
   a    b   c
```

The file above is read fine.
But some of the files look as follows

```
   a      
   a    b   c
   a    b   c
   a    b   c
```

And for this file the error is as follows

```
    pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 3
```

The problem cant be solves by skipping the first line, as we are unsure that second like is in correct format or not. The major thing is how to specify the desired nuber of columns.

I know that we could fill not available values.

But , how could I specify the number of columns in csv reader such that it doesnt get confuse with the error in the first row, if we skip the first row only, perhaps, the second row is also problematic.

Thanks

Cheers

Comment: you can specify your separator when reading the files, may be some files are not comma separated!

Comment: I am using the tab separateor

Comment: I have edited the question and provide the samples.

Comment: Does `header=None, skiprows=1` do what you want? All that `header=None` does is consider the first row as a data row instead of a header row... so if that's always invalid, `skiprows=1` will only start counting rows as actual data from the 2nd line.

Comment: Yes, but you never know if the 2nd row is also problematic. The problem is that to specify the number of columns, irrespective of the file formatting problem. The missing values can be filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

names parameter made the trick:

```
df = pd.read_csv(fname, '\t', header=None, names=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

Returns:

```
    A   B   C
0   a   NaN     NaN
1   a   b   c
2   a   b   c
3   a   b   c
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I would be going for.

Answer (score 0):

you can try specifying that your separator is a tab and every missing value will be filled with `NaN`:

```
d=pd.read_csv('test.csv',sep='\t', header=None)
```

and get:

```
   0    1    2
0  a  NaN  NaN
1  a    b    c
2  a    b    c
3  a    b    c
```